# mac error: pkg-config not found (even if pkg-config is already installed)

Tags: package, admin

I have read several posts about this.
But they didn't solved from mine.

Please see the information

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Finish install then

```
Rangers-iMac:dash ranger$ which pkg-config
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config
```

It means pkg-config is installed.

```
Rangers-iMac:dash ranger$ ./configure
...
checking for exit in -lboost_chrono-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... yes
checking for dynamic linked boost test... yes
configure: error: pkg-config not found.
```

it means configure can't find pkg-config.

I think the problem is in PATH, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: which wouldn't find pkg-config if it weren't in the path already. Maybe the configure-call does something weird. What packet do you want to build?

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/dashpay/dash/blob/master/configure.ac#L702 - maybe that’s the culprit. Try setting the environment Variable to your executable. .

Comment: export VAR=value is pretty much all you need to know. in this case it's export PKG_CONFIG=/path/to/pkg-config

Comment: Neat. Please consider editing your question too, putting more information about the package you actually try to build already in there. I think that should help discovery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The project's configure-script seems to make assumptions about the location of pkg-config. Luckily you can override it using the PKG_CONFIG environment variable.

```
export PKG_CONFIG=/path/to/pkg-config
```

Then `./configure` again.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using eclipse CDT,in the project>Properties>c/C++ build>Environment, add:

```
variable:PKG_CONFIG
value:/usr/local/bin/pkg-config
```

then clean the project, all is well.
For some other includes not resolved problems, you can add directories in project>Properties>c/C++ General>Paths and Symbols:GNU C++ > includes

Answer (score 0):

You can install pkg-config via homebrew:

```
brew install pkg-config
```