# Compiling a github action in rust that requires openssl

Tags: rust, openssl, github-actions

i'm trying to compile a rust project that uses git2-rs as a crate. The crate requires openSSL.

When the action runs, it gets stuck on trying to compile openssl and fails. It seems that openssl needs to be configured on the action as vendored, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
2024-02-26 22:49:21.231 xcodebuild[3572:15576] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/h1/8hndypj13nsbj5pn4xsnv1tm0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-26-02_22-49-0021.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx11.1" cannot be located.
2024-02-26 22:49:23.238 xcodebuild[3694:15828] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/h1/8hndypj13nsbj5pn4xsnv1tm0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-26-02_22-49-0023.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx11.1" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'macosx11.1'
    Updating crates.io index
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded tempfile v3.10.1
  Downloaded git2 v0.18.2
  Downloaded libssh2-sys v0.3.0
  Downloaded libgit2-sys v0.16.2+1.7.2
  Downloaded libz-sys v1.1.15
   Compiling libc v0.2.153
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.30
   Compiling vcpkg v0.2.15
   Compiling tempfile v3.10.1
   Compiling native-tls v0.2.11
   Compiling tokio-native-tls v0.3.1
   Compiling hyper-tls v0.5.0
   Compiling reqwest v0.11.24
   Compiling diqwest v1.2.1
   Compiling cc v1.0.88
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.101
   Compiling libz-sys v1.1.15
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.101`
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/runner/work/test-cli/test-cli/target/release/build/openssl-sys-fb0f92e5fd6c90fe/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AARCH64_APPLE_DARWIN_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  AARCH64_APPLE_DARWIN_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AARCH64_APPLE_DARWIN_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  AARCH64_APPLE_DARWIN_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=AARCH64_APPLE_DARWIN_OPENSSL_DIR
  AARCH64_APPLE_DARWIN_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_aarch64-apple-darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_aarch64_apple_darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-apple-darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_apple_darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-apple-darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_apple_darwin
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  run pkg_config fail: pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation.
  Install a sysroot for the target platform and configure it via
  PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, or install a
  cross-compiling wrapper for pkg-config and set it via
  PKG_CONFIG environment variable.
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-sys-0.9.101/build/find_normal.rs:190:5:
  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.
  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.
  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.
  $HOST = x86_64-apple-darwin
  $TARGET = aarch64-apple-darwin
  openssl-sys = 0.9.101
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Error: Process completed with exit code 101.
```

My project is pretty small:

```
❯ cargo tree -i cc
cc v1.0.88
[build-dependencies]
├── libgit2-sys v0.16.2+1.7.2
│   └── git2 v0.18.2
│       └── test-cli v0.6.1 (/Users/jd/projects/test-cli)
├── libssh2-sys v0.3.0
│   └── libgit2-sys v0.16.2+1.7.2 (*)
├── libz-sys v1.1.15
│   ├── libgit2-sys v0.16.2+1.7.2 (*)
│   └── libssh2-sys v0.3.0 (*)
└── openssl-sys v0.9.101
    ├── libgit2-sys v0.16.2+1.7.2 (*)
    └── libssh2-sys v0.3.0 (*)
```

The bash script that compiles the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Building Test CLI"

SDKROOT=$(xcrun -sdk macosx11.1 --show-sdk-path) MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0 cargo build --release --target=aarch64-apple-darwin

echo "Packaging Binaries"

cd target/aarch64-apple-darwin/release
tar -zcvf "$1.tar.gz" test-cli
```

The action:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]

name: Dev

jobs:
  macos:
    name: Build - MacOS
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Change folders
        run: ''
      - name: Set up cargo
        uses: dtolnay/rust-toolchain@master
        with:
          toolchain: 1.74
          target: aarch64-apple-darwin
      - name: Cargo Cache
        uses: Swatinem/rust-cache@v2
      - name: Compile and package Test CLI
        run: ./ci/build-macos.sh test-cli-macos
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812712/mac-error-pkg-config-not-found-even-if-pkg-config-is-already-installed.

Comment: You're using `macos-latest` ([currently pointing to macOS 12](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md#utilities)) and that [has `pkg-config` preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md#utilities) on it. So, most probably, it is related to above thread. On the other hand, on `macos-13` runner, it doesn't seem to be preinstalled, see https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7632.

Comment: Thank you Azeem, 

i've looked at the thread, but I don't know what i'm suposed to do. I added the config and still produced errors. 

Sorry for being such a noob, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In stdout, the error is about `pkg-config` and that's what the above threads are about. In stderr, it says that you don't have OpenSSL dev libraries installed. You need to install those first according to the runner you're using.